# Setting environmental variable for SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to import an existing project in Android Studio but after the gradle setup , the following error occurs:

> [SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the
>   local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable. 
>   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)]

Comment: chnage your sdk location drom File-project Structure and change path of SDK

Comment: set the sdk location in you ide local properties so it will point to the SDK.

Comment: @karthik: Check your project has `local.properties` or not? If yes specify, sdk location over there!